# Detect if a web site is already open and reuse window

Tags: php, javascript, url, window

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to open a url link in an email and reuse a window if a certain page ( or site ) is already open.
What I have is a 'forgot password' page where the user enters their email address and gets asked a security question, this then sends a plain text email with a url link (so no html link attributes) and reports to the user that it has done a good job . When the user clicks on the link it opens up a shiney new browser window and ignores the old report page leaving it feeling sad and unwanted. I would like to know if there is a way to reuse this window or more specifically the forgot password report page. Perhaps I could name the page with javascript or detect if the url is already open somehow. 
Or is it possible if I did decide to use an html email, so most people would get the benefit.

Please help my report page to loved and wanted again.
Thanks

I am using PHP and I could use javascript or jquery browserside, or anything else that might fit in with this

Comment: There's no (reliable) way to do this. I don't actually know of *any* way to do it, but I'm willing to believe there's some obscure hook between (say) Outlook and IE that might allow it.

Comment: Did you open the window with `window.open`?

Comment: Your pages have feelings huh? :)

Comment: If this would be possible, it would be a security issue (privacy).

Comment: I'm happy this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely up to the browser to decide; some browsers might be able to guess what you're trying to do and replace an existing tab with the new page, but on the whole that doesn't make sense.

This is what you could do (though it's not really technical):

1. after the email is entered and submitted, the form page changes and asks them for the security code that's being sent to them.
2. inside the email you print the security code in a clear manner for the user to double-click and copy to their clipboard; they would then switch to their browser again (with your page still open) and paste the value. You can still provide the link for ease of the user, of course.

Btw, to make an easily selectable code for the user to copy into their clipboard I found that using `base32` encoding is the best; those codes can be selected easily, even with iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the page opened by the email send out a [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) request and have the other page answer that is is still open.  If that happened, the new tab could close immediately.

However, switching between tabs/windows is something happens at the OS or browser level, not the page level, and there is no way to switch to the open tab using JavaScript.  You could write a browser extension to do it, but that's probably innapropriate for something so trivial, and no one would bother to install it.