# Prevent duplicate windows/tabs

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, email-verification

I've set up email verification for my website.

Once the user registers, they are prompted to verify their account via a link that has been emailed to them. If the user clicks the link, it activates their account and brings them to a log in screen, but of course in a new tab.

Maybe I'm OCD, but my issue is that If somebody goes to verify their account immediately after registering it without closing the first tab, they will have two tabs opened at the login screen after clicking the verification link. **Is there any way to prevent this or use the same tab if a tab with the same domain is already open? Or are there better architectures to use?**

I've set up the verification process so that there are two separate tables in my database.

## `users_unverified` (table A)

**`account_email | account_password | token | entry_time | num_id (primary)`**

## `users_verified` (table B)

**`account_email | account_password | joined | ...`**

The process can be broken down like so:

1. A user registers with an email and password, which creates a token
2. The token is emailed to them with a verification link
3. Once the user registers via the link (if the token matches and has not expired), `account_email` and `account_password` are transferred from `users_unverified` to `users_verified` and a confirmation message is displayed
4. The record in `users_unverified` is deleted

**Is there a different and or better way to do this, which will allow me to avoid the possibility of two tabs being opened at the same time?**

Comment: you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852459/detect-if-a-web-site-is-already-open-and-reuse-window

Comment: @Juakali92 give me a second to read it

Comment: @Juakali92 yes, that was very similar. it would be nice to hear more responses, however

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I don't think you don't need to worry about it, the user will understand that clicking a link in an email will open a browser tab and they then complete the process.

Though if you do want to do it you can use `localStorage` to set state that a window is already open, and use `BroadcastChannel` to send data between the tab (for example sending a hash back to your window so you can either show the DOM which askes to verify their email or do a redirect)

Here is an example:

This javascript would be on the register page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var channel = new BroadcastChannel("linkopened");
    channel.onmessage = function(e) {
        // do something with data sent from other tab
        alert('Email link opened, show DOM or redirect: ' + e.data)
    };

    localStorage.setItem('pageopen', true);
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        localStorage.removeItem('pageopen');
    };
</script>
```

And this would be on the page which opens in a new tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (localStorage.getItem('pageopen')) {
        var channel = new BroadcastChannel("linkopened");
        channel.postMessage('Some special link or hash');
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks so much. i'll test it out when i get a minute. have u heard of window.postmessage()?

Comment: That's what channel.postMessage is doing, second thought I dont think the `window.close()` will work if opened from say gmail. But you could send an event to focus, but your still be left with an open tab.